# How do I capture elements in my nested objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have an **Array** called `transactions`. The elements in the **Array** are a collection of objects. The objects in turn have nested elements.
How do I capture the nested elements in the objects, in particular, the value of the element called `transPayersNumber`?

Find below the structure of my **Array**:

```
transactions[
    {numberOfMobileTransactions: 200, day: Wednesday,
     phoneNumbers: [{ _id: 60bdf6c18fd22aac8c4b35f2,
                        transPayersNumber: '0705667966',
                        transCounty: 'Kiambo'
                     }] 
     },

    {numberOfMobileTransactions: 120,day: Tuesday, 
     phoneNumbers: [{ _id: 60bdf6c1654622aac8c4b35f2,
                        transPayersNumber: '0747897933',
                        transCounty: 'Kiambo'
                     },
                     { _id: 60bdf6sdtd4622aac8c4b35f2,
                        transPayersNumber: '0747845631',
                        transCounty: 'Nairobi'
                     }] 
     }
]
```

How do I access the value of the element in the nested **Object** `transactions.phoneNumbers.transPayersNumber`?

In a failed attempt to access the value of the `transPayersNumber` element I tried a variety of codes but the code below is as far as I have gotten without any error messages:

```
transactions.forEach(transactions => {
    console.log("Transactions: " +transactions.day + " by: " +transactions.phoneNumbers )
});
```

The code above yeilds:

```
Transactions: Wednesday by: {
  _id: 60bdf6c18fd22aac8c4b35f2,
  transPayersNumber: '0705667966',
  transCounty: 'Kiambo'
},
Transactions: Tuesday by: {
  _id: 60bdf6c18fd22aac8c4b35f2,
  transPayersNumber: '0705667966',
  transCounty: 'Kiambo'
},
Transactions: Tuesday by: {
  _id: 60bdf6c18fd22aac8c4b35f2,
  transPayersNumber: '0705667966',
  transCounty: 'Kiambo'
}
```

My desired output would be something similar to the below:

```
Transactions: Wednesday by: 0705667966
Transactions: Tuesday by: 0747897933, 0747845631
```

Comment: `phoneNumbers` is an array, just like `transactions` is an array. You managed to enter and iterate `transactions` correctly, just do the same for `phoneNumbers`.

Comment: @JeremyThille `transactions.phoneNumbers.transPayersNumber`  doesnt seem to work for me. Kan you kindly show me in code?

Comment: @JeremyThille

`transactions.forEach(transactions => {
    console.log("Transactions: " +transactions.day + " by: " +transactions.phoneNumbers.transPayersNumber  )
});`

Doesnt seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
const transactions = [
  {
    "numberOfMobileTransactions": 200,
    "day": "Wednesday",
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "_id": "60 bdf6c18fd22aac8c4b35f2",
        "transPayersNumber": "0705667966",
        "transCounty": "Kiambo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "numberOfMobileTransactions": 120,
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "_id": "60 bdf6c1654622aac8c4b35f2",
        "transPayersNumber": "0747897933",
        "transCounty": "Kiambo"
      },
      {
        "_id": "60 bdf6sdtd4622aac8c4b35f2",
        "transPayersNumber": "0747845631",
        "transCounty": "Nairobi"
      }
    ]
  }
];


const transPayersNumbersArray = [];

transactions.map(eachObj => {

  const phoneNumbers = eachObj.phoneNumbers;
  
  if (phoneNumbers && phoneNumbers.length) {
   phoneNumbers.map(eachPhoneNumberObj => {
      transPayersNumbersArray.push(eachPhoneNumberObj.transPayersNumber);
   })
  }

});

console.log('TransPayersNumbersArray ==>', transPayersNumbersArray)
```